# Passing DataTypes in @helper Asp.net MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following helper:

```
@helper BuildSubMenu(dynamic link, int activePageId)
{
...
        @foreach (IPublishedContent item in link.Children.Where("Visible"))
        {
           @item.GetPropertyValue("pageTitle") // NOT WORKING
        }

}
```

And i have this code outside:

```
@foreach (IPublishedContent item in link.Children.Where("Visible"))
            {
               @item.GetPropertyValue("pageTitle") // WORKING            
            }
```

IPublishedContent (dataType) works well outside the helper, but inside it does not work, it behaves as a variable instead.

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit and include the missing code. What works well outside the helper? Inside it's a variable? It's hard to grasp what you're asking.

Comment: Please edit that int your question.

Comment: OK, its updated now, please check

Comment: Are you sure that `link` is passed properly to BuildSubMenu?

Comment: Yes, it works fine for the rest of the code insider BuildSubMenu, and the foreach works well to, only IPublishedContent  datatype is not defined inside helper :( and i dont know how ti fix, that. It's a umbraco data type.

Comment: The output is: Our.Umbraco.Vorto.Models.VortoValue, which is wrong